# Select current line in outlook vba

Tags: vba, email, outlook, selection

I wrote a function in outlook vba. When i click on a mail and use my function, it automatically create my reply mail with all i used to put on my replies mails.

My reply mail looks like this :

**Hi Mister**

**It's done !**

**Regards,**

Because i'm the bdd admin, i receive a lot of task from mail, so i used to send mail only with "it's done" on it.

But sometimes, i use my automatic reply to reply to a normal mail, which not contains any kind of task to do. So i have to manually delete the "it's done" from my reply mail before write my reply.

With the "SendKeys" function, my cursor is automatically put at the line of the "It's done", but now i'm trying to automatically select this line. Because if this line is already selected, i'll just have to write something to replace the "It's done", or i could send the mail like it if i just want to send "It's done".

But i looked for "Select text in vba outlook" or "Select row" or even "select sentence" and "select line", i found nothing clear to solve my problem. How can i do the trick ?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found how to do this :

```
    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
        Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
        Dim objDoc As Word.Document
        Dim objSel As Word.Selection

    Set objOL = Application
        If objOL.ActiveInspector.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
            Set objDoc = objOL.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
            Set objNS = objOL.Session

            Set objSel = objDoc.Windows(1).Selection
            objSel.MoveEnd Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1

        End If
    Set objOL = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
```

Thanks for your attention !